# j2store add to cart button

Tags: joomla-3.x, j2store

I'm trying to add J2Store add to cart with below code

```
templates/name-template/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

code

```
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/helpers/j2store.php');
$product = F0FTable::getAnInstance('Product', 'J2StoreTable')->getClone();
            if($product->get_product_by_source('com_content', $this->item->id)) {
            echo $product->get_product_html();
        }
```

and load cart use this code

```
<?php echo $product->get_product_cart_html();?>
```

this code show cart button but not work

after click add to cart button no action for add product to cart

How can i do after click add to cart buuton , add product at cart?

**Solution**

this problem is conflict javascript j2store...i updated j2store to latest version (3.3.9) solved this problem

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. What HTML markup does your code generate?

Comment: @Sharky thank you so much .. this problem is conflict javascript j2store...i updated j2store to latest version (3.3.9) solved this problem